# (ClaimsIdentity) System.Security.Claims in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, claims-based-identity

I can see from [Mono Status](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.5&profile=4.5&assembly=System) that System.Security.Claims is not implemented. Does anyone know if it's possible to implement "ClaimsIdentity" in Mono? Is there a project that handles Claims based Identity in Mono?

Comment: Is there any workaround for this. Anyone has run into the same issue. I need to have access to the IPrinciple interface and Claims, how I can do that in Mono-runtime in linux?

Comment: I'm very new to mono development, but running into the same issue.

Comment: ClaimsIdentity is not implemented in Mono. Here is a discussion you can keep an eye on. https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1190 hopefully we can see it implemented sometime soon.